# Trigonometry Table Problem

Tags: trigonometry

Evaluate the given trigonometric expression:
\[
\frac{5\sin^2 30° + \cos^245° - 4\tan^2 30°}{2\sin30°\cdot\cos 30° + \tan 45°}
\]

Comment: I had inserted the value of given trigonometric values, like sin30=1/√2. And so on. But I am not satisfied with my answer

Comment: $\sin 30^{\circ} = 0.5$.

Comment: @Alpha: You are almost certainly expected to give an *exact* expression. It is an exercise in trig functions of "standard" angles. You may be expected to rationalize the denominator.

Comment: The entity to be evaluated is an expression, not a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**: Posted below are some identities/axioms. $$\begin{aligned}\sin 30^{\circ} &=  0.5 \\ \\ \sin 45^{\circ} &= {1 \over \sqrt 2} \\ \\ \cos 30^{\circ} & = {\sqrt3 \over 2} \\ \\ \cos 45^{\circ}& = {1 \over \sqrt 2} \\ \\ \tan \theta &= {\sin \theta \over \cos\theta } \\ \\ \sin^2\theta &= (\sin\theta)^2 \\ \\ \tan^2\theta &= (\tan\theta)^2 \\ \\ \cos^2\theta &= (\cos\theta)^2 \\ \\ n\sin\theta &= n \times \sin \theta \end{aligned} $$